# Take last value in sequence

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database, data-manipulation

I am trying to insert data into my target table from my source table where in the target table I have an additional column called **SaleTo**.

**SaleTo** = the SaleFrom based on the MAX SaleSequence.

Example of the source table:

| SaleNo | SaleFrom | SaleSequence |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alabama | 2 |
| 1 | Minnesota | 1 |
| 1 | Virginia | 3 |

Example of target table:

| SaleNo | SaleFrom | SaleSequence | SaleTo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Alabama | 2 | Virginia |
| 1 | Minnesota | 1 | Virginia |
| 1 | Virginia | 3 | Virginia |

Some code I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.SaleNo, 
                MAX(a.SaleSequence ) AS SaleSequence,
                b.SaleFrom
FROM SequenceOrderSource a
INNER JOIN SequenceOrderSource b
ON a.SaleNo= b.SaleNo
--WHERE B.SaleFrom IN (SELECT b.SaleFrom FROM SequenceOrderSource HAVING SaleSequence= MAX(SaleSequence))
GROUP BY a.SaleNo, b.SaleFrom
```

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: Where does the SaleTo located? and What if more than 1 SaleTo has same SaleSequence which is MAX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `last_value`. The default range is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` so you need to specify the clause explicitly.

```
SELECT SaleNo, SaleSequence, SaleFrom,
   last_value(SaleFrom) over(partition by SaleNo order by SaleSequence RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) SaleTo
FROM SequenceOrderSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this situation another way is using of CROSS APPLY. Somethings like this code:

```
SELECT SaleNo, SaleSequence, SaleFrom, OrderData.SaleFrom AS SaleTo
   CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 SaleFrom FROM SequenceOrderSource 
                ORDER BY SaleSequence DESC) OrderData
FROM SequenceOrderSource;
```